# Functions of Mixing random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, time-series, mixing

If $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent random processes that are $\alpha$-mixing, is a linear combination, $aX_t + bY_t$ also $\alpha$-mixing? What about other functions $f(X_t,Y_t)$? How does one approach a problem like this?

In particular I am interested in if $\mathbf{Z}_t$ is $\alpha$-mixing where $Z_{t,i} = \delta_{i,X_t} - \delta_{i,Y_t}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is Kronecker's Delta $(i=1,\ldots,k)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that if $f\colon\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$ is Borel-measurable, then 
for each $I\subset\mathbb Z$, $\sigma\left(f(X_t,Y_t),t\in I\right)\subset \sigma\left((X_t,Y_t),t\in I\right)$. Therefore, it suffices to estimate the mixing coefficients of the sequence $\left((X_t,Y_t)\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z}$. By approximation, it suffices to estimate for a fixed $n$ the quantity 
$$\left|\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j=-m}^0\{(X_j,Y_j)\in B_j\}\cap 
\bigcap_{j=n}^{n+m}\{(X_j,Y_j)\in B_j\}\right)-\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j=-m}^0\{(X_j,Y_j)\in B_j\}\right)\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j=n}^{n+m}\{(X_j,Y_j)\in B_j\}\right)\right|,$$
where $B_j$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which can be written as a finite disjoint union of products of Borel subsets of the real line. Using independence, we can show that 
$$\alpha\left(\left(\left(X_t,Y_t\right)\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z},n\right)
\leqslant \alpha\left(\left(X_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z},n\right)+
\alpha\left(\left(Y_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z},n\right).$$

Comment: Davide Giraudo, can you give references for the last result, where the mixing coefficient of the pair is less equal than the sum of each mixing coefficients?

Comment: As you are experienced with this subject, could you please look to a related question here that I just made: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453624/check-the-alpha-mixing-conditions-stochastic-process

Comment: @CelineHarumi It is Theorem 6.2 in Bradley, R, Introduction to strong mixing conditions. Vol. 1, Kendrick Press, Heber City, UT,2007. MR 2325294

Comment: I will have a look at your question in these days.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is very useful, I wonder what can be said when we only know that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are uncorrelated and not necessarily independent, or furthermore when there is some dependence between the two processes.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo should I ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @DylanDijk Yes, it would be good if it is asked as a separate question. I would certainly upvote and try to address it.